# Joining two mysql select statements where the second statement uses a column in first

Tags: php, mysql

I apologize in advance if this is super simple for some, but I'm not quite sure how to phrase the question to get relevant search results/answers to it. I'm also new to this. I thank you for your time in advance to look at my question.

I have two tables:

#1 - `quote_requests` . This is where all data is saved once a customer submits a quote request. This has a primary id called `id`.

#2 - `quote_messages` . Here are all the replies for all quote_requests. Basically a chat back and forth between the client and the sales rep. There's a column called `quote_id` that identifies the quote_requests' column `id`

So what I do in PHP is first run this statement

`` SELECT * FROM `quote_requests` WHERE `archived` = 0 AND `owner_id` != 0 AND `owner_id` = 64 ORDER BY `id` DESC ``

Then I go through the results with a while in PHP, with the purpose of seeing who was the last person that replied to the messages on that particular quote request: was it the client or the sales rep?

`` SELECT `reply_as`, `member_id` FROM `quote_messages` WHERE `quote_id` = :quote_id ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1 ``

Now obviously this is very bad because it takes 40 seconds for the page to process.

My question is:
How do I combine these two select statements into one considering that the second select statement is tied into the results of the first one. `quote_id` of `quote_messages` being the same as `id` of `quote_requests`

Thank you so much!

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . your method might be fine if there are not too many quote requests.

So, I might start just by using indexes on the existing queries:

- `quote_requests(owner_id, archived, id desc)`
- `quote_messages(quote_id, id desc)`

However, if you are doing a loop in PHP (which your question is not really explicit about), then you might want to run just one query in the database instead of a loop.

If I understand correctly the one query would look like:

```
SELECT qq.*
FROM (SELECT qm.quote_id, qm.reply_as, qm.member_id,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY qm.quote_id ORDER BY qm.id DESC) as seqnum
      FROM quote_requests qr JOIN
           quote_messages qm
           ON qr.quote_id = qm.quote_id
      WHERE qr.archived = 0 AND qr.owner_id = 64
     ) qq
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

And for this you want the same indexes above.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Gordon! By setting an index on `quote_id` in the `quote_messages` table The script runs in 0.4s instead of 40s. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you once again! I love how you wrote this, seems so nice, although I have no clue what is going on :) . I've replace ON qr.id = qm.quote_id and the script works. The results are not what they should be, but the solution seems more complicated than what I'd want to get into. The index solution fixed the loading times. Thank you so much for all your help and effort Gordon.

Comment: It's phenomenal. Thank you so much @Gordon! P.S. I would upvote the response, but I need 15 rep to upvote. As soon as I hit the mark, *in Arnolds voice* I'LL BE BACK :)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions for this to replace the while loop

1. Fetch for all quotes in a single query

```
SELECT `reply_as`, `member_id` 
FROM `quote_messages` 
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT MAX(id) 
    FROM `quote_messages` 
    WHERE `quote_id` IN (:quote_ids)
    GROUP BY ID
) AS a
```

2. adding 2 columns in `quote_requests` which will maintain the latest `reply_as`, `member_id`

Comment: Thank you aRvi, unfortunately the script doesn't run. Also :quote_ids is a PDO statement. So it should link to `quote_messages`.id

Comment: after fetching from 1st SQL query then you will get the list of query_id, then using those query_ids you can add that list in the above SQL query.